# RESTful web service in C# code

Tags: c#, service, rest

How do I consume a RESTful web service in C# code without wcf? Something very simple

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the WebRequest class. See [A REST Client Library for .NET, Part 1](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!657.entry).

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code to invoke a RESTful web service.

```
string responseMessage;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(serviceUrl);
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Method = method;
HttpContent objContent = HttpContentExtensions.CreateDataContract(requestBody);
if(method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
{
    //byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingXmlSer(requestBody, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService");
    byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingDataContractSer(requestBody);
    request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
    using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
    //request.Timeout = 60000;
}

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
else
{
    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
}
```

The above code needs to refer the following namespaces:

1. using Microsoft.Http; --> Available from the REST Starter Kit (Microsoft.Http.dll)
2. using System.Net;
3. using System.IO;

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta) project - it is a REST Architecture Solution Targeting Asp.net.